# Save workflow history when workflow restarts

Tags: list, workflow, 2016, workflow-history

Is there anyway to save the old workflow history when workflow restarts? I'm using sharepoint 2016.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**.

There is no way to save the workflow history of old workflow instance in New workflow instance.

But If you want to see the workflow history logs of old instances then you can open the **workflow history list** associated with that particular workflow.

Default workflow history can be found at below location:

```
http://[servername]/[sitename]/lists/Workflow%20History
```

Also, you can get the name and URL of workflow history list associated for particular workflow from workflow settings in SharePoint designer.

Comment: Your link worked like a charm. It's not very friendly but It is what I need for now. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome. Glad to hear that.